# Why is this Java UDP packet length too long?

Tags: java, udp, client, packet

So I have a java server and client, the data is being sent to the server fine and the server is interperating it, but i found that the client takes ages to respond to what the server has sent it, after some time looking around i found that the data my server is sending the client is way longer than the data that should be sent.

The packet that is sent to the client has all the data that I sent however it also has a lot of white space after it, I would like to fix this, anyone have any ideas?

My code to get the data is a simple for loop of every client on the server, this adds the client data to a string and that string is added to a packet:

class PlayerList

```
public static String getString()
{
    String message = "";

    for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
    {
        Player player = list.get(x);

        if(message.equals(""))
        {
            message += player.name+";"+player.address+";"+player.pos[0]+";"+player.pos[1]+";"+player.fakeRotation+";"+player.rotation+";"+player.rotationSpeed+";"+player.speed+";"+player.sheildEnabled+";"+player.sheildStrength+";"+player.health;
        }
        else
        {
            message += ","+player.name+";"+player.address+";"+player.pos[0]+";"+player.pos[1]+";"+player.fakeRotation+";"+player.rotation+";"+player.rotationSpeed+";"+player.speed+";"+player.sheildEnabled+";"+player.sheildStrength+";"+player.health;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(message);

    return message;
}
```

Class Send

```
while(Server.serverRunning)
    {
        for(int p = 0; p < PlayerList.list.size(); p++)
        {
            Player player = PlayerList.list.get(p);

            try
            {
                byte[] buf = PlayerList.getString().getBytes();

                //send the message to the client to the given address and port
                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, player.address);
                Server.socket.send(packet);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't send packet to player: "+player.name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know the data recieved from the getString method is correct and has no white space as I have tested it, so it must be happening when i add the string to the packet.

The intended data shows up in the output as:
    `Luke;127.0.0.1:63090;50.0;50.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;true;100;100`

however the actual data shows up on the client as:
    `Luke;127.0.0.1:63090;50.0;50.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;true;100;100 (lots of spaces here) ...line is too long, please switch to wrapped mode to see whole line...`

The client code to receive the data is:

```
receiveData = new byte[clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                receiveMessage = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to create datagram with buf.length size but you are sending only player.address. So, remaining space is filled with spaces.

Comment: You haven't shown the *client* code which receives the packet.

Comment: The packet has whitespace at the end of it or it has \0 s?  It may be padding it out to its default packet size with nulls.

Comment: im sending to player.address with buf as my data

Comment: buf has a length of 60 so it should send fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getData on DatagramPacket returns the entire buffer, which may have extra data at the end. You need to call getLength() to determine the actual length of data received, and only look at those bytes from getData()

```
byte[] realData = Arrays.copyOf( receivePacket.getData(), receivePacket.getLength() );
```

Comment: So to solve the data length issue on sending the data i could change this to byte[] realData = Arrays.copyOf( PlayerList.getString().getBytes(), PlayerList.getString().getBytes().length );

Comment: No, your sending is fine, it is the receiving that is the problem.

Comment: Hmm, then I cant see why the server takes so long to send the data, when i press a key on the client, the server receives the data instantly and does the translation on the data instantly too, but it takes a while for that data to show up on the client.

Comment: My answer was just in respect to you getting extraneous data on the client. I need to see more of your code (client and server) to see if there is something wrong that would cause delays. Can you verify by pinging between the client and server that the latency is the same in both directions? If the latencies are significantly different, then it is likely a network issue, not a problem with your code.

Comment: I can confirm that the data sending from the client to the server is a lot quicker than the data sending from the server to the client.

Comment: Turns out you were right, I also had to change a few things on the server and add some thread sleep commands as the server was using a lot of cpu!